# Multiple color fills in matplotlib markers

Tags: matplotlib, colors, marker

I want to use multiple colors in a marker made with matplotlib. Doing two colors was not that difficult, following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/filledmarker_demo.html), and with some additional info from [this documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html). However, I was wondering if it is possible to make a marker with more than 2 colors. I'm in a situation where I want a single marker to actually get 3 different colors (a point on a map refers to three different observations).

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html

Comment: @tom does that also work with normal plots (plt.plot(..))?

Comment: @tom or other markers

Comment: See my answer for how to modify that example to use it with `ax.plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by following the matplotlib example shown here:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html

Below I have changed the example slightly to use `ax.plot` instead of `ax.scatter`.

Basically this means all your marker must have the same size, and instead of using the `s` kwarg for `scatter`, you use the `ms` (or `markersize`) kwarg for `plot`.

Also, instead of `facecolor` you need to define `markerfacecolor`.

Other than those changes, everything else remains the same as the original example.

```py
"""
This example makes custom 'pie charts' as the markers for a scatter plot
    
Thanks to Manuel Metz for the example
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first define the ratios
r1 = 0.2       # 20%
r2 = r1 + 0.4  # 40%

# define some sizes of the scatter marker
sizes = np.array([60, 80, 120])

# calculate the points of the first pie marker
#
# these are just the origin (0,0) +
# some points on a circle cos,sin
x1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, r1))
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, r1))
xy1 = np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x1, y1])])
s1 = np.abs(xy1).max()

x2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(r1, r2))
y2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(r1, r2))
xy2 = np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x2, y2])])
s2 = np.abs(xy2).max()

x3 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(r2, 1))
y3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(r2, 1))
xy3 = np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x3, y3])])
s3 = np.abs(xy3).max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Here's where I made changes
ax.plot(np.arange(3), np.arange(3), marker=xy1,
           ms=20, markerfacecolor='blue', markeredgecolor='None', linestyle='None')   # I changed this line
ax.plot(np.arange(3), np.arange(3), marker=xy2,
           ms=20, markerfacecolor='green', markeredgecolor='None', linestyle='None')  # I changed this line
ax.plot(np.arange(3), np.arange(3), marker=xy3,
           ms=20, markerfacecolor='red', markeredgecolor='None', linestyle='None')    # I changed this line


plt.margins(0.05)
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This code gives the error- `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: @lsr729 you are correct. Seems some things have changed in matplotlib since I wrote that. I've updated it based on the changes to the gallery example and it should work again now

Comment: Hello, this works good, how can I add the legend as a single point instead of three different scatter points